# MySQL server root user deleted, can't connect to server

Tags: mysql, root

Somehow I must have deleted the root user and now I am getting messsages that localhost cannot connect to the server so I pretty much can't do anything at the moment. I tried to reinstall the server but for some reason there is no root account created.

Is there some kind of hidden file on my computer that is disallowing connections from localhost despite me completely removing the server application?

Some have suggested using --skip-grant-tables and adding a root user but I just get a message that localhost can't connect to the server. It's madness, can't I just create another server instance with a root account or something?

Comment: http://www.helpfromfriend.com/database/mysql/how-to-recreate-root-account-in-mysql/

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work, -u root gives the message that localhost can't connect.

Comment: You need to give us complete information -- "messages that localhost cannot connect" is not sufficiently useful.  Please post the *exact* error message that you are seeing, including the letters and numbers before and after the error.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
    'mysqld_safe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL ser
ver

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>

Comment: It looks like there is no mysqld_safe bin on Windows... Then maybe this will help You http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/10/10/resetting-the-root-password-with-mysql-on-windows.aspx or http://learnmysql.blogspot.com/2012/07/reset-mysql-root-password-in-windows.html

Comment: Still doesn't work thanks anyway. Bloody awful software this MySQL server is. Will have to re-ghost my os.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the root user using the method described in section C.5.4.1.1

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

However, instead of an update of the password put the following SQL in the text file:

```
use mysql;

insert into user (Host, User, Password) values ('localhost','root','');

update user set Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',Create_priv='Y',Drop_priv='Y',Reload_priv='Y',Shutdown_priv='Y',Process_priv='Y',File_priv='Y',Grant_priv='Y',References_priv='Y',Index_priv='Y',Alter_priv='Y',Show_db_priv='Y',Super_priv='Y',Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',Lock_tables_priv='Y',Execute_priv='Y',Repl_slave_priv='Y',Repl_client_priv='Y',Create_view_priv='Y',Show_view_priv='Y',Create_routine_priv='Y',Alter_routine_priv='Y',Create_user_priv='Y' where user='root';

flush privileges;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but localhost couldn't connect to the server, so I can't send any sql commands. In the end I just reformatted lol.